# Why should I escape translatable strings? and how shall i do that?

Tags: translation, escaping

Is it really need to escape translatable strings?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really need to escape translatable strings?

Yes. If a string is translatable then that means its value can be changed from an external source. This means it's not safe.

> and how shall i do that?

See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/) on how to escape with WordPress.

When it comes to translatable strings, there are two main functions to use: `esc_html__()`, `esc_attr__()`, `esc_html_e()`,  and `esc_attr_e()`. These functions are essentially just `esc_html()` and `esc_attr()` combined with the `__()` or `_e()` translation functions.

The thing you need to be aware of is that escaping should happen as late as possible. Ideally the last thing that happens before output. In your screenshot you appear to be just defining strings for later use. In that case you wouldn't use `esc_html__()` at this point. Instead you'd just use `__()` and then use `esc_html()` whenever you actually output the string.

Here's a couple of good resources on the topic:

- https://tomjn.com/2015/05/07/escaping-the-unsecure/
- https://wpvip.com/documentation/vip-go/validating-sanitizing-and-escaping/

Comment: Thank you , so that means if i am doing  echo __('Error : The post type is not WooCommerce Product','pgggo'); it should be echo esc_html__('Error : The post type is not WooCommerce Product','pgggo');

Comment: Right. Or just use `esc_html_e()`, which also echoes.

Comment: Perfect. thanks