# When outputting a static string to the page, is it necessary to escape the output?

Tags: escaping

In my code I'm using the _e() function to echo static text onto the page:

`_e( 'Plugin name not found.', 'opn_td' );`

Is this safe, or do I need to escape this output?

- As I understand (from WordPress documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) and [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/)), escaping needs to occur only if there is a chance the output could be malicious or undesirable.  Is that the case here?  It seems to me like 'no.'  But PHP Code Sniffer (in VSCode) has flagged this as a violation of WordPress coding standards, indicating:

`All output should be run through an escaping function (like esc_html_e() or esc_attr_e())...`

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQumg.jpg).

- I agree that 'escape everything' is the safest option, and not difficult to implement--I have no problem doing so in this case.  But I'm more interested in learning how much of a security risk this particular line of code actually introduces.
- I understand the value of `esc_html_e()` when outputting dynamic content, and will certainly use it in those cases.

Thanks.

Comment: This text _is_ dynamic. `_()` and `_e()` allow the text to be replaced by translations or filters. They need to be escaped, as the code sniffer is telling you.

Comment: @JacobPeattie OK got it.  So in light of that, when would `_e()` ever be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I escape translatable strings? and how shall i do that?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/338724/why-should-i-escape-translatable-strings-and-how-shall-i-do-that)

Comment: Either function could be used if you were capturing the text/value and escaping it later (you should escape as late as possible).

Comment: Maybe `_e()` is for cases in which you actually do NOT want to escape output?  For example, maybe you WANT to output specific HTML to a page?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I meant, why would one ever use `_e()` instead of `esc_html_e()` (or other escape-and-echo functions)?

Comment: And I answered you?

Comment: OK then I'm not sure I follow. Can you give me an example of when I might use `_e()` instead of `esc_html_e()`?

Comment: @cag8f I hope you are still around and can tell me what PHPcs you used to actually get WP Coding Standards considered? I just installed PHPcs 3.6 and of course do not get anything related to WP - only annoying messages about not to use whitespace after opening parenthesis in function call (which is totally not WP Standard :P )

Comment: @BedaSchmid It was all so long ago, and I've moved away from WordPress, so I haven't used the coding standards in some time, and can't remember what version of phpcs I was using.  But I can say that getting a linter up and running in my text editor (VSCode) which enforces the WordPress Coding Standard rules (for PHP, CSS, and JavaScript) wasn't the smoothest exercise.  Lot's of hiccups.  But I eventually got them all working.  I basically started from the WP Coding Standards repo and followed their instructions: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards

Comment: @cag8f thanks that has helped me to find and install the WPCS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The [`_e()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/) function displays a translated string; so 1) You're actually echoing a dynamic text; and 2) Yes, you should escape a translated string.*

Relevant excerpt taken from the [internationalization security guide](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/security/#escape-internationalized-strings) in the [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/):

> #### Escape Internationalized Strings
>
> *You can’t trust that a translator will only add benign text to their localization; if they want to, they could add malicious JavaScript or
>   other code instead.* To protect against that, it’s important to
>   **treat internationalized strings like you would any other untrusted input**.
>
> If you’re outputting the strings, then they should be escaped.
>
> **Insecure:**
>
> ```
> <?php _e( 'The REST API content endpoints were added in WordPress 4.7.', 'your-text-domain' ); ?>
> ```
>
> **Secure:**
>
> ```
> <?php esc_html_e( 'The REST API content endpoints were added in WordPress 4.7.', 'your-text-domain' ); ?>
> ```

### In response to your comment:

> example of when I might use `_e()` instead of `esc_html_e()`

So based on the excerpt from the internationalization security guide, I believe we should just use [`esc_html_e()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html_e/) and avoid using `_e()` unless we are 100% *certain* that a translation is *completely* clean from malicious code and special characters (apart from the basic ones like dots/`.`, hypens/`-` and spaces).

And one may want to use `_e()` because he/she wants HTML code (e.g. `b`, `a`, etc.) in the translation to be interpreted (e.g. `<b>hey</b>` would visually show `hey` in bold like so: **hey**):

```php
// if the translation was '<b>Enviar</b>' (in Spanish), then 'Enviar' would
// visually be in bold
_e( 'Submit' );
// equivalent to echo __( 'Submit' );

// but here, the text would remain as-is ('<b>Enviar</b>')
esc_html_e( 'Submit' );
// equivalent to echo esc_html( __( 'Submit' ) );
```

But then, instead of using `_e()`, one should use [`__()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/) and with functions like [`wp_kses_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_data/), [`wp_kses_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_post/) or [`wp_kses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) which allows us to control the list of allowed HTML tags and attributes (e.g. we can allow/disallow `href`, `onclick`, etc.). And despite these functions do not guarantee that the output is actually secure, using them is at least better compared to simply echoing the raw HTML:

```php
// what if the translation was 'Enviar <script>some bad JS code</script>' ?
_e( 'Submit' );

// wp_kses_data() by default disallows/removes <script> and </script> tags.
// sample output: 'Enviar some bad JS code' - doesn't look good.. but better
// than the browser executing the bad JS script.
echo wp_kses_data( __( 'Submit' ) );
```

Nevertheless, if one can ensure that a translation is secure (e.g. by moderating a translation), then using `_e()` would not be a problem — and in fact, it's simpler (just one single function call)...

### Resources

- [How to Internationalize Your Plugin](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/)
- [Internationalization Security](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/security/)
- [Securing Output » Custom Escaping](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/#custom-escaping)

### Notes

- The WordPress core also calls `_e()` without escaping the HTML output... e.g. [`_e( 'Enter your password to view comments.' );`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.3/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1561) and that distracted my focus in writing the previous versions of this answer. Nonetheless, I'm not going to comment further on that possibly insecure `_e()` calls..
- And just so you know, I'm not a security expert. :)

Comment: OK thanks for that, it all indeed makes sense, and I've marked it as the answer.  But you mentioned, "Use _e() when you want HTML tags in the translated string to be interpreted," and you gave an example.  I understand how using _e() in this situation would be required in order to display the `<b>` tag.  But technically, isn't this also insecure?  If a translator adds undesirable code, wouldn't that code be executed in this example?

Comment: Good catch. :) And I hope the updated answer helps you with that..

Comment: OK thanks for all that!

Comment: I decided to revise the answer one last time.. (for now). I hope you're okay with that..

Comment: "So based on the excerpt from the internationalization security guide, I believe we should just use esc_html_e() and avoid using _e() unless we are 100% certain that a translation is completely clean from malicious code and special characters (apart from the basic ones like dots/., hypens/- and spaces)."  That's my understanding as well.  "The WordPress core also calls _e() without escaping the HTML output... e.g. _e( 'Enter your password to view comments.' );"  Curious.  It's difficult to believe they made a mistake there.  More likely is that we're overlooking something.

Comment: Anyway, for now I'm fine with escaping everything.  Thanks for your time and insight.

Comment: You're very welcome. And btw, the moderation thing was also based on the second resource listed in the answer - but we all know about hooks (which can change almost everything), so let's just take good security measures on our sites.